# Replace Property of de object ANGULARJS

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, object

I have an object and array from which I want to obtain a new object to show in the way below..

**Group (Array)**

this is the array and get of te services.

```
[
  {
    "IdQuestion": "5de12577fcfabc3c50660d36",
    "idSurvey": "5de12546fcfabc3c50660d35",
    "titleQuestion": "Porque compró el producto?",
    "IdQuestionOption": "5de125b7fcfabc3c50660d39",
    "idSurveyQuestion": "5de12577fcfabc3c50660d36",
    "option": "Sabor"
  },
  {
    "IdQuestion": "5de12585fcfabc3c50660d37",
    "idSurvey": "5de12546fcfabc3c50660d35",
    "titleQuestion": "Cómo se entero del producto?",
    "IdQuestionOption": "5de125cbfcfabc3c50660d3c",
    "idSurveyQuestion": "5de12585fcfabc3c50660d37",
    "option": "Periodico"
  },
  {
    "IdQuestion": "5de125a8fcfabc3c50660d38",
    "idSurvey": "5de12546fcfabc3c50660d35",
    "titleQuestion": "Con cuanta periodicidad consume el producto",
    "IdQuestionOption": "5de125f8fcfabc3c50660d40",
    "idSurveyQuestion": "5de125a8fcfabc3c50660d38",    //the property is here.
    "option": "Diario"
  }
]
```

**Result (Object)**

this is the Object and i generate with  select radios buttons with ng-models

```
{
  "5de125a8fcfabc3c50660d38": "5de12601fcfabc3c50660d42", //the property is up.
  "5de12585fcfabc3c50660d37": "5de125f0fcfabc3c50660d3f",
  "5de12577fcfabc3c50660d36": "5de125c1fcfabc3c50660d3b",
  "Age": "5",
  "Gender": "1",
  "IdSurvey": "5de12546fcfabc3c50660d35"
}
```

**I need create a OBJECT**

i need create this object for export to services

```
{
  "Q03": "5de12601fcfabc3c50660d42",
  "Q02": "5de125f0fcfabc3c50660d3f",
  "Q01": "5de125c1fcfabc3c50660d3b",
  "Age": "5",
  "Gender": "1",
  "IdSurvey": "5de12546fcfabc3c50660d35"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
 let res={
      "5de125a8fcfabc3c50660d38": "5de12601fcfabc3c50660d42", //the property is up.
      "5de12585fcfabc3c50660d37": "5de125f0fcfabc3c50660d3f",
      "5de12577fcfabc3c50660d36": "5de125c1fcfabc3c50660d3b",
      "Age": "5",
      "Gender": "1",
      "IdSurvey": "5de12546fcfabc3c50660d35"
       }





  res["Q03"] = res["5de125a8fcfabc3c50660d38"]
  delete res["5de125a8fcfabc3c50660d38"]
  res["Q02"] = res["5de12585fcfabc3c50660d37"]
  delete res["5de12585fcfabc3c50660d37"]
  res["Q01"] = res["5de12577fcfabc3c50660d36"]
  delete res["5de12577fcfabc3c50660d36"]
```

Solution 2

```
  let res={
      "5de125a8fcfabc3c50660d38": "5de12601fcfabc3c50660d42", 
      "5de12585fcfabc3c50660d37": "5de125f0fcfabc3c50660d3f",
      "5de12577fcfabc3c50660d36": "5de125c1fcfabc3c50660d3b",
      "Age": "5",
      "Gender": "1",
      "IdSurvey": "5de12546fcfabc3c50660d35"
       }
     let changed={
       "Q03": res["5de125a8fcfabc3c50660d38"],
       "Q02": res["5de12585fcfabc3c50660d37"],
       "Q01": "res["5de12577fcfabc3c50660d36"],
       "Age": res.Age,
       "Gender": res.Gender,
      "IdSurvey": res.IdSurvey

       }
```